# bash get first element before the first integer of a variable

Tags: bash, shell

I want to get the first element before the first integer of a variable,
For example, I have this variable:

```
FILE=normalize-component-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-package-58.jar
```

And I want to get the application name which is the name "normalize-component" in that case that always comes before an integer.

Take in mind that the application name can always change but the structure will always be:

```
{application_name}-{digit}-{*}-jar-with-dependencies-package-{digit}.jar
```

desired output:

APP_NAME=normalize-component

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in bash:

```sh
$ FILE="normalize-component-0.0.3-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies-package-58.jar"

$ echo "${FILE%%-[[:digit:]]*}"
normalize-component
```